Detector Sensor Not Detecting
I have a problem with my Microwave Sensor V2.0 Contraption.
When I turn it on it doesn't detect anything.
The LED-light is also not flickering so I know it probably has something to do with that, but I don't know where to begin with tweaking it.
Here below is the Code:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MsTimer2.h>           // Timer interrupt function library
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
#define OLED_RESET     -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3D
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

int pbIn = 0;                    // Define interrupt 0 that is digital pin 2
int ledOut = 13;                 // Define the indicator LED pin digital pin 13
int number = 0;                  // Interrupt count
volatile int state = LOW;        // LED state, initially off (LOW)

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledOut, OUTPUT); // Set LED pin as output
    attachInterrupt(pbIn, stateChange, FALLING); 
    // Set interrupt function: triggered on FALLING edge (pin 2 goes from HIGH to LOW)
    MsTimer2::set(3000, Handle); // Timer interrupt: call Handle() every 3000ms (3 seconds)
    MsTimer2::start(); // Start timer interrupt

    display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.display();
}

void loop() {
    // Display "status" and the current number on the OLED
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0, 5);
    display.println("status: ");

    display.setTextSize(3);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0, 30);
    display.println(number);

    display.display(); 
    display.clearDisplay();
    delay(10);
}

void stateChange() { 
    // Interrupt service function: increment the counter when triggered
    number++;
}

void Handle() { 
    // Timer service function: reset the counter and toggle the LED state
    number = 0;               // Reset counter
    state = !state;           // Toggle state (HIGH to LOW, or LOW to HIGH)
    digitalWrite(ledOut, state); // Set the LED to the toggled state
}

Here is a picture of the little contraption:
I don't have a sketch for tinytronics, because some components I can't find on the website.
Sorry if the pictures might be a little too big.
And for clarification The LED-light is this yellow light on the back of the Microwave Sensor V2.0
I thank you for taking your time looking at this.






Your variable number should be declared volatile too

I did that but it hasn't fixed it.

The wire of of the 5v should've been the d2pin and vice versa. The blueprint I got it off made a error. I fixed it
